# Process created by Process.Start() terminates when the parent application is closed

Tags: c#, linux, process, mono

I'm using C# and Mono 2.10.2 on Debian 6.

So the scenario is that I created a process with Process.Start() like the following:

```cs
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "/home/lucy/";
p.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/sh";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/home/lucy/test.sh";

p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ShellProc_ErrorDataReceived);

p.Start();
```

The shell script which is in this case called test.sh is ran which does several things including starting a java application. The problem I am recieving is when the c# application is terminated the bash script/java application also terminates.

I have looked at several other similar questions posted here on Stack Overflow and none come to an obvious conclusion, including this one:

[How to create a Process that outlives its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008886/how-to-create-a-process-that-outlives-its-parent)

According to some users and supposedly the docs, processes created by Process.Start() should not be terminated when the application terminates, but obviously in my case that is not true. So could this be a Mono related issue and if that is indeed the case then is there any alternatives to how I'm doing it now as I am out of ideas.

Comment: It definitely does not happen in Windows, so yes this must be something mono/nix specific.

Comment: Post your update as a new answer and then mark it as solution, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 1/Solution:** This actually was not mono's fault and was indeed my own fault, the answer below helped me come to the conclusion that it was something else in my application that was causing the processes started by the application to terminate when the application terminates and the actual thing that was causing this was some GC stuff, specifically GC.Collect(), my fault, sorry and I hope this helps anybody who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete sample that works for me:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Tick {
  static void Main(string[] args) {  
    Process p = new Process();

    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/sh";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "test.sh";

    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandle(ShellProc_ErrorDataReceived);

    p.Start();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (5000);
    Console.WriteLine ("done");
  }  
  static void ShellProc_ErrorDataReceived (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs ea)
  {
  }
}
```

and then test.sh is:

```sh
while true; do
    date;
    sleep 1;
done
```

When I run the sample from a terminal, the test.sh script will continue to output data after the sample program has exited.

Comment: Thanks, after testing this I realized the problem was completely my fault in the first place, it was some GC stuff being called in another area of the application that was causing the processes created by the application to close. You helped me realize where I went wrong, thanks!