# how to make a truly independent process in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, process, wpf-controls

I know that we can use `Process.Start` static method for creating independent processes but the problem I am facing is that whenever I close off my original program it ends up closing the process I created.

I checked in task manager/process explorer and saw that the process is still in the hierarchy. So I tried to invoke it using cmd.exe (like an intermediate process) which finally made my target program split off from the process tree. But the closing behavior did not change at all.

I tried using both `Application.Current.Shutdown` as well as `this.Close()` in the program for closing my original but both have same behavior. It seems like my application is keeping track of all processes spawned, but i have not written anything of the sort, and killing them off when closing.

Any idea why this is happening? I am creating the process inside an event handler method for a button click could that be the reason? Can it be fixed with the Process class or do I need to use some lower level stuff?

The code used for process creation:

```
try
{
   ProcessStartInfo rn = new ProcessStartInfo();
   rn.CreateNoWindow = false;
   rn.UseShellExecute = true;
   rn.FileName = "cmd.exe";
   rn.Arguments = String.Format(" /C start {0} -t:{1} {2}", ExeFile, Pass, User);
   rn.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   Process.Start(rn);
}
catch(Exception ec)
{
   MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Unable to Start Client: {0}", ec.Message), "Error Starting Client", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

}
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008886/how-to-create-a-process-that-outlives-its-parent

Answer (score 0):

Check your command "cmd.exe /C start ExeFile -t:pass user" if it works correctly or not.
I think, ExeFile crashes.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I already checked if its crashing on its own  by commenting the shutdown method. There were no crashes.

Comment: What's your OS? I tested it on xp and framework 4 with no problem.

Comment: im using Win7 HP 64 bit. Did you put the code in an event handler? im using this inside a button click event handler

Comment: Yes I did.let me try it on 64 bit win7

Comment: I tested it with win7 64 bit and framework 4, no issue found.

Comment: Have you tested WaitForInputIdle() after start the process? You need to create a new instance of Process