# How to manage multiple projects

Tags: c#

I have 2 projects in 1 solution: `MainApp` and `Updater`. I want to open `Updater` from `MainApp`, thus I added `Updater` as a reference in `MainApp`. Everything is ok, but I can't close `MainApp` for updating. When I close `MainApp`, `Updater` is closed also.

This is how to call `Updater`:

```
Updater.frmUpdater f = new Updater.frmUpdater();
f.serverPath = "http://127.0.0.1/qlhd/";
f.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate process to do what you want to do.  Don't reference updater directly, instead you'll need to use `StartProcess`

[See here for more information and a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008910/265419)

Answer (score 0):

as James says, you need to start it in a separate process

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "updater.exe";
p.Start();
```

or simply

```
Process.Start("updater.exe");
```

note, for "updater.exe" to work, the exe needs to in the same folder as your main application.
also note
if you use the first example you can use p.WaitForExit(); to wait for the process to finish before doing anything else.

you can start the process with arguments (like serverpath)

`p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-P http://127.0.0.1/qlhd/";`

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx) if you need help with creating arguments for your updater

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to change the main form at runtime.

```
Updater.frmUpdater f = new Updater.frmUpdater();
ApplicationContext.MainForm = f
f.serverPath = "http://127.0.0.1/qlhd/";
f.Show();
```

Untested, but this would allow you to close the `MainApp` without also exiting the `frmUpdater`.

**edit**

I'm not sure how to access an application's `ApplicationContext` after it's been started, but I know this can be done somehow.

I also recall a setting that lets you choose between "exit when main form is closed" or "exit when all forms are closed". But it seems to be implemented in VB.NET only.

In C#, you can achieve the same results by changing the `Main()` method in Program.cs by not passing the `MainApp` form as a context.

Instead of:

```
Application.Run(frmMainApp);
```

You'd write:

```
Application.Run();
frmMainApp.Show();
```

Anyway, as pointed out by @Dan, you can't run an updater in the same process as the program that needs updating. Not unless the updater itself launches another process (e.g. a ClickOnce installer). But that would make your updater project almost completely redundant.

Comment: (Assuming that the implication in the question is correct, and that the OP is trying to run an auto-update mechanism.) You have to use `Process.Start` for this mechanism to work, otherwise `mainapp.exe` is still running. What you've suggested will allow you to close the main *form*, but that doesn't help with the update process as the original `.exe` is still hosting the new form.

Comment: That's true. My solution is pretty much worthless when you look at it like that.