# Disown a child process from .net-core tool

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, unix, .net-core

I have a tool which runs a ssh command so I can connect to the linux pc via reverse ssh. When I want to update my tool, written in `.Net Core 2.1`, the updater will stop the process of the tool and update the files. But by stopping the tool the ssh process, started before with `Process.Start()`, will be closed, too, as the ssh process is a child process from the tool.

Is there any way to "disown" the child ssh process from my tool so I wont loose connection while the updater runs?

Running Ubuntu...

C#:

```
case UssGatewayFunction.NPIConnectSSH:
    Log.Information("Connect to MyCompany via ssh");
    try
    {
        Process.Start("ssh", "-R 3521:localhost:22 -p 9450 myuser@1.2.3.4 sleep 30");
        response = new DefaultRes(true, UssGatewayFunction.NPIConnectSSH);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error($"Can't start ssh: {ex.Message}");
        response = new DefaultRes(false, UssGatewayFunction.NPIConnectSSH);
    }
```

Updater.sh:

```
systemctl stop gateway.service
if pgrep "gateway" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
        #here i loose the ssh connection
        pkill -x "init-gateway" || true
        pkill -x "gateway" || true
fi
#now just the extracting happens
```

Comment: I don't think that processes started with `Process.Start()` die after their parents are killed. I did a quick Google and this confirmed it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008886/how-to-create-a-process-that-outlives-its-parent. In fact, to kill a child process when the parent dies, you'll need to go through a lot of hoops since it's not the default behaviour. Are you sure killing your .NET process definitely kills the SSH? Can you try it with "calc.exe" as per the example in that link and verify that it's definitely dying when your updater runs?

Comment: It's not windows but Linux.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
 [DllImport("libc")]
 private static extern int system(string exec);
 
 system($"nohup {command} >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Infos : [system](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), [nohup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and)